# Silhouette analysis on KMeans clustering

Tags: python, numpy, cluster-analysis, k-means, silhouette

How to fix this error? Why did the code fail to visualize plot?

```
TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Input

```
data_sillet = np.loadtxt('clustering_sillet.csv', delimiter=',')
data = data_sillet.astype(int)
data
```

Output

```
array([ 2,  3,  8, 29, 32, 15, 23,  0,  4, 16, 14, 15,  1,  5,  1,  8,  0,
       30, 14,  0,  1,  4,  5,  2, 12,  1,  7,  2,  0,  3, 22,  7,  1,  5,
        0,  6,  0, 15,  9, 24, 24,  5,  0,  0, 24, 11,  9,  0,  0,  1, 18,
       11,  4,  8, 27,  1,  3,  4,  7, 17,  5,  0,  1, 16])
```

Input

```
data =data(n_samples=64,n_features=1,centers=3,cluster_std=0.5,random_state=101)    
plt.scatter(data[0][:,0],data[0][:,1],c=data[1],cmap='rainbow')
```

Output

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-89-0b73209258a0> in <module>()
----> 1 data =data(n_samples=64,n_features=1,centers=3,cluster_std=0.5,random_state=101)
      2 
      3 plt.scatter(data[0][:,0],data[0][:,1],c=data[1],cmap='rainbow')

TypeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object is not callable
```

Comment: it seems that you called 'data' instead of 'KMeans' in this line:
data =data(n_samples=64,n_features=1,centers=3,cluster_std=0.5,random_state=101)

Comment: The code failed because it tried to call (call is detected by round brackets right after it) 'data' with parameters n_samples=64, etc. Because numpy.ndarray is not a callable type, which means there is no __call__ function defined for it, this code raises 'TypeError' before scatterplot gets called and plot is visualized. That's why you don't see plot

Comment: Oh..I see. Thank you.

Comment: I posted this explanation as an answer since otherwise this question will be seen as unanswered and won't help anyone

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you called 'data' instead of 'KMeans' in this line:

```
data =data(n_samples=64,n_features=1,centers=3,cluster_std=0.5,ra‌​ndom_state=101)
```

Fix:

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans 
data =KMeans(n_samples=64,n_features=1,centers=3,cluster_std=0.5,ra‌​ndom_state=101)
#remaining code follows
```

The code failed because it tried to call (call is detected by round brackets right after it) `data` with parameters n_samples=64, etc. Because `numpy.ndarray` is not a callable type, which means there is no call function defined for it, this code raises `TypeError` before scatterplot gets called and plot is visualized. That's why you don't see plot.

Comment: I got the error message after I conducted the above code.  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-a53eebd3355a> in <module>()
----> 1 data =KMeans.data(n_samples=64,n_features=1,centers=3,cluster_std=0.5,random_state=101)

AttributeError: type object 'KMeans' has no attribute 'data'

Comment: Omit the `.data`. And **try to *understand*, not just copy&paste**. Otherwise you'll never learn to fix such trivial typos yourself.